# How to update opencart jquery to lastest with no change code?

Tags: php, jquery, opencart, javacv

OpenCart latest (1.5.6) using jquery 1.7.1 , we have compiled some modules  using jquery 1.9.1, also I do not want to change the file

```
  admin / view / template / common / header.tpl
```

I know just change the code in that file things easy,

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

but I do not want to change it, because they need updating in many different versions of OpenCart, therefore, no way to remove that library and running the latest jquery library, but does not change the content of the file's default OpenCart!

Thanks for caring and helping

Comment: so... change everything, without changing anything?

Comment: Marc B , i need change jquery only ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If You need jQuery 1.9.1 only for some few modules, then You could include the jQuery 1.9.1 only in these modules controller:

```
class ControllerModuleMyModule extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Hopefully this will not collide with already loaded 1.7.1.

But if You have a lot of modules requiring 1.9.1 (e.g. that extra loading will end up in jQuery 1.9.1 being loaded on each page), I recommend to use only jQuery 1.9.1, walk through all the OpenCart, identify and remove the incompatibility of current OpenCart's JS code to make it compatible with the latest 1.9.1. You should do this even if only one module requires this new library, but I understand that there might not be so much time left...